# Most efficient way to convert java.lang.Long to primitive int

Tags: java, performance, casting

I have a weird scenario where I need to convert several million `java.lang.Long`s into primitive `int` types. I need to do this several times a day, every single day. Normally, I wouldn't worry about this kind of simple casting, but since it's happening so much, so often, I have to ask: what's the most efficient way to do this, and why?

My first attempt:

```
Long myLong = getLong();
int x = Integer.valueOf(myLong.toString())
```

Although this seems like going 3 sides around the barn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: WARNING: Value of `Long` may not fit in an `int`

Comment: Just use `intValue()`, and recognize you'll lose data unless your longs are restricted.

Comment: Do not convert `Long` to `String` and tha parse it to get an `int`.

Comment: If your values fit in an `int`, replace your `Long` variables by `Integer`

Comment: Why -1? Problem is well defined and code sample is given.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `Long` class has an `.intValue()` method, I guess this is what you are looking for...

(warning, you may lose precision etc etc -- but you probably know that already)

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
int x = myLong.intValue( );
```

Comment: I am getting the error: Cannot invoke intValue() on the primitive type long

Comment: @Anand.  `myLong` has to be declared as `Long` not `long`.  For latter case just cast it, i.e. `(int) myPrimitiveLong`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
Integer i = (int) (long) b;
```